# calling different function depending on type

Tags: c++, templates, conditional-statements

I want to call different functions in a templated function depending on the type, like this:

```
template<typename T>
T func() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value || /* other allowed types */ , "Type not allowed");

    T ret {};
    // if T == int
    funcInt(&ret);
    // if T == /* other types */
    /* other functions */

}
```

Is such a thing possible?

I tried this:

```
std::function< int(*T)> query;
if (std::is_same<T, int>::value) {
    query = funcInt;
}
```

but this gives me an error:

> error: 'T' does not refer to a value

Comment: I think that should be `std::function< int(T*)> query;`, assuming it is a pointer to `T` argument?

Comment: Oops! Shame on me, and I thought it was some weird template error ...

Comment: if I read you correctly, you will still have errors, since your `query` can't store functions with signature of arguments of types not convertible to T*

Comment: @Piotr S.: T are only types that are convertible to T*.

Comment: @gartenriese: ok, I thought of more universal solution but it's fine then

Comment: @Piotr S.: It's just a wrapper for tinyxml2 with its QueryInt/Float/...  functions, so I don't have to make it universal. Thanks for the input though,  if you want to answer this question with a more general solution, go ahead, I will gladly upvote it and it might help others who might need a more universal approach!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is_same` can be used in `if` statements just fine:

```
if (std::is_same<T, int>::value>) { /* stuff */ }
if (std::is_same<T, float>::value) { /* other stuff */ }
```

Altough this checks are in theory done at runtime, the compiler knows all values at compile time and will most likely remove any dead braches. The downside is that the entire code in `func` needs to be syntacticaly and sematically well formed, regardless of what `T` is. This may not be always feasible.

The proper template-ish way would be something like this:

```
template<typename>
struct helper;

template<>
struct helper<int> { static void do_work() { /* stuff */ } };

template<typename T>
T func()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<T, int>::value || /* other allowed types */ , "Type not allowed");
    helper<T>::do_work();
}
```

This allows you to write common stuff in `func` and put the rest in specializations.

OTOH, if the signature of `func` is really this simple and there wouldn't be much code duplication, you might as well specialize `func` itself.

Comment: "[...] needs to be syntacticaly well formed [...]". Does that mean I can't call a function that takes an int, because the parameter could also be a double, for instance?

Comment: I think you might be able to remove the requirement to be well formed through SFINAE.

Comment: @gartenriese You can, because a double is convertible to an int, but it is probably not want you want to happen. I may have worded this sligtly weirdly - what won't work is [something like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f3314362bbd748a), for example. It may not be a problem for you.

Comment: Yes, I want a double to stay a double and and int to stay an int. Thanks for the explanation! I will use specialized functions for now, they just consist of one function call, so that's okay.